# Finding Direction to Maximize Clearance

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, geometry

I have multiple points representing obstacles in an x,y plane. For a given point within that environment, how would I find which direction will maximize my clearance?

For example, in the picture below, there are 3 point-obstacles (in black), and the point I want to move so it gets the most clearance (in red). The arrow is the direction it should move in to most quickly maximize its clearance from all other points.

[image]

With a single obstacle this is trivial, but I don't really know how to do it with multiple obstacles.

Comment: How do you define clearance?

Comment: The red arrow seems a strange solution. For the first pixels the distance to the right black one is decreasing.

Comment: @Ash, the goal is to move in a direction that most quickly maximizes the distance from the red point to all other points.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? I think this is far too broad/vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution to your problem is to define a cost function such as

```
f(red_pt, black_pts)=sum_i norm2(black_pts[i]-red_pt)
```

and maximize it. A quick and dirty solution is to use gradient ascent, *e.g.*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def toy_problem():

    x=np.array([
        [10,5],
        [3,4],
        [5,10]]).astype("float")

    init_pt=np.array([[6,5]]).astype("float")

    return x, init_pt


def cost_function(x, black_pts):

    s=0
    jacobian=np.zeros([1,2])
    for i in range(black_pts.shape[0]):
        a=x[0,0]-black_pts[i,0]
        b=x[0,1]-black_pts[i,1]
        nrm2=a**2+b**2
        jacobian[0,0]+=2*a
        jacobian[0,1]+=2*b
        s+=nrm2

    return s, jacobian


def gradient_ascent(x, cost_function, black_pts,num_it=20):

    lr=1e-2
    for i in range(num_it):

        val, jacobian=cost_function(x,black_pts)

        x=x+lr*jacobian

        plt.plot(black_pts[:,0],black_pts[:,1],"k*");
        plt.plot(x[0,0],x[0,1],"r*");
        plt.show()

    return x

if __name__=="__main__":

    black_pts,init_pt=toy_problem()
    x_final=gradient_ascent(init_pt,cost_function,black_pts)
```

To have faster convergence, *i.e.* as you put it, move away faster in the direction that minimizes the distance to black points, you could use second-order optimization algorithms such as [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm). Once you have defined your cost function, finding the direction that increases the distance faster is a matter of selecting a good optimization method and hyperparameters.

Animated, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Your code appears to be plotting something... are you planning to share the image please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The plots are just here to illustrate the evolution of the optimized parameters (the red point) during gradient ascent. It wouldn't be very meaningful to share individual images. I think the best way would be to just copy-paste and run the code.

Comment: I have added an animation. I hope you don't mind. Feel free to delete it if you wish.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Good idea, it does look a lot better! Quick question though:  what did you use to generate the gif? I would have saved the plots and used something like ffmpeg but that seems like a clunky solution...

Comment: I just replaced your `plt.show()` with something like `plt.savefig(f"f-{i:03}.png")` and let it run. Then at the end, I used **ImageMagick** to make an animated GIF with `magick -delay 80 f-*png -loop 0 animated.gif`

Comment: Oh, I forced the `y` limits of the plot too, to prevent the graph axes changing, using `plt.ylim(2,11)`